# How to store HTML data in a database field?

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to write some code for the [Image marker](http://drupal.org/project/imagemarker) module to allow an HTML description to be stored in the database. Currently all text is escaped and stored as plain text.

The module stores x/y coordinates and descriptions as name/value pairs in a database field, for example:

```
x=208&y=251&id=208-251&description=wheel;x=77&y=142&id=77-142&description=light
```

Can I store HTML descriptions this way? Is there a better way to store this kind of data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to add to imagemarker?

Comment: the ability to store HTML. Currently, when you enter any HTML it gets stored escaped and the HTML won't render when displayed. I'm also looking for a best practice when storing data. The structure above just doesn't look like "best practice" to me ;-)

Comment: If all you want is html in this module's markers, why don't you just take the check_plain()s out of its code (and Drupal.checkPlain out of JS) and keep your fingers crossed that your users won't do anything nasty in there?

Comment: great idea. I removed the Drupal.checkPlain from the JS and tried to use check_markup($description, 'plain_text') instead of check_plain() in the module. However the HTML I added to the db didn't get filtered. I might have to post a separate question about that.

Comment: Can't compress it and store it in blob?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Assumption:** You can't just point Image marker to this table of yours and it will figure out the rest itself. You will need some amount of *php code*, to make the module do what you want. For example you will pass your data on to a theme function.

**Proposition:** It seems to me like it would be better to serialize an array like this:

```
array(
  0 => array('x' => 208, 'y' => 251, 'id' => '208-251', 'description' => 'wheel'),
  1 => array('x' => 77, 'y' => 142, 'id' => '77-142', 'description' => 'light'),
);
```

and store the serialized data? That, or create a 4 table column, one column for each type of value. That should make it easier to pass the information on to Image marker, as opposed to using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which I assume you will need to do if you store a long string of HTML.

On a more general note, I would generally avoid storing already escaped data in the DB. There may come a time when you do want to use the data in an un-escaped fashion, which could become a huge mess of regexp to reverse the escape. One example is if you load, edit, and re-save the data, you will have & escaped into & when you load, which in turn will become &amp; when you escape the data *again* for saving.

Escaping data is, in my opinion, for display of data, not storage. That said, if you are absolutely certain you will *never* need the un-escaped data again, then you could avoid one potential security hole.

Comment: thanks! Great points. Is storing serialized arrays used often in contrib modules? Does the Field API provide a good way to store this data or is that overkill when you have only few fields?

Comment: Serialized anything has a performance hit because your module has to load it (at least 1 query) and then decode it (processor cycles). Also you can't do SQL against any of those elements, so if you wanted to find all images with description of 'wheel' you'd be in trouble. But to see serialization in action, look at the {variable} table.

Comment: I don't see how either of your arguments make sense, given the assumption I've stated. Decoding in some form will be required anyway, and doing SQL against s:5:"wheel"; isn't that far from doing SQL against on=wheel;x=77. My assumption could still be wrong, but MotoTribe has yet to respond to that. I added a sentance suggesting for a 4 column solution instead, which possibly removes the weaknesses all together.

Comment: I think serializing the array is the way to go. I also like your advice about storing the HTML unescaped. I don't have a need to query against the values. Eventually I want to use it to "tag" users similar to Facebook abut I would use an additional user reference field for that.

Answer (score 4):

Basic info about [user input sanitization in Drupal](http://drupal.org/writing-secure-code).

Comment: links are not answers in this QA site

Comment: True, but you really need to know The Drupal Way for handling user input, especially HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure you want to be escaping all the text, especially if the description gets to be long.

You might be better served by creating a new table, keyed on the marker's id, using a longtext field to store the html.